# Spring State machine - Table Scripts

Tags: spring-statemachine

Am new to Spring state machine.

I have configured the states & transitions in  a  configuration file, using which am able to orchestrate my micro-services successfully.

Now am planning to persist the states & transitions in an external repository (MYSQL DB)

When i tried to do that using JpaStateMachineRepository, am getting SQL Exception saying state_machine doesn't exists.

So 2 questions
1. Do we have readily available scripts for creating state machine tables.
2. Is it possible to have custom tables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a liquibase version of tables for Spring Statemachine

```xml
<changeSet id="00001" author="Alexander Biryukov">
    <comment>Spring State Machine JPA changelog</comment>

    <!-- main tables -->
    <createTable tableName="action">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="spel" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="deferred_events">
        <column name="jpa_repository_state_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="deferred_events" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="guard">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="spel" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="state">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="initial_state" type="boolean"/>
        <column name="kind" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="machine_id" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="region" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="state" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="submachine_id" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="initial_action_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="parent_state_id" type="bigint"/>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="state_machine">
        <column name="machine_id" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="state" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="state_machine_context" type="blob"/>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="transition">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>

        <column name="event" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="kind" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="machine_id" type="varchar(255)"/>

        <column name="guard_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="source_id" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="target_id" type="bigint"/>
    </createTable>

    <!-- many to many binding tables -->
    <createTable tableName="state_entry_actions">
        <column name="jpa_repository_state_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="entry_actions_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="state_entry_actions"
                   columnNames="jpa_repository_state_id, entry_actions_id"
                   constraintName="pk_state_entry_actions"/>

    <createTable tableName="state_exit_actions">
        <column name="jpa_repository_state_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="exit_actions_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="state_exit_actions"
                   columnNames="jpa_repository_state_id, exit_actions_id"
                   constraintName="pk_exit_entry_actions"/>

    <createTable tableName="state_state_actions">
        <column name="jpa_repository_state_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="state_actions_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="state_state_actions"
                   columnNames="jpa_repository_state_id, state_actions_id"
                   constraintName="pk_state_state_actions"/>

    <createTable tableName="transition_actions">
        <column name="jpa_repository_transition_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="actions_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="transition_actions"
                   columnNames="jpa_repository_transition_id, actions_id"
                   constraintName="pk_transition_actions"/>

    <!-- foreign keys -->
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="deferred_events"
                             baseColumnNames="jpa_repository_state_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_deferred_events"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state"
                             baseColumnNames="initial_action_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_initial_action"
                             referencedTableName="action"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state"
                             baseColumnNames="parent_state_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_parent_state"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="transition"
                             baseColumnNames="guard_id"
                             constraintName="fk_transition_guard"
                             referencedTableName="guard"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="transition"
                             baseColumnNames="source_id"
                             constraintName="fk_transition_source"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="transition"
                             baseColumnNames="target_id"
                             constraintName="fk_transition_target"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_entry_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="entry_actions_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_entry_actions_a"
                             referencedTableName="action"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_entry_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="jpa_repository_state_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_entry_actions_s"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_exit_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="exit_actions_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_exit_actions_a"
                             referencedTableName="action"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_exit_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="jpa_repository_state_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_exit_actions_s"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_state_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="state_actions_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_state_actions_a"
                             referencedTableName="action"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="state_state_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="jpa_repository_state_id"
                             constraintName="fk_state_state_actions_s"
                             referencedTableName="state"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="transition_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="actions_id"
                             constraintName="fk_transition_actions_a"
                             referencedTableName="action"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="transition_actions"
                             baseColumnNames="jpa_repository_transition_id"
                             constraintName="fk_transition_actions_t"
                             referencedTableName="transition"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"/>
</changeSet>
```

or alternatively SQL version:

```sql
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
create table action (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), spel varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table deferred_events (jpa_repository_state_id bigint not null, deferred_events varchar(255))
create table guard (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), spel varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table state (id bigint not null, initial_state boolean, kind integer, machine_id varchar(255), region varchar(255), state varchar(255), submachine_id varchar(255), initial_action_id bigint, parent_state_id bigint, primary key (id))
create table state_entry_actions (jpa_repository_state_id bigint not null, entry_actions_id bigint not null, primary key (jpa_repository_state_id, entry_actions_id))
create table state_exit_actions (jpa_repository_state_id bigint not null, exit_actions_id bigint not null, primary key (jpa_repository_state_id, exit_actions_id))
create table state_state_actions (jpa_repository_state_id bigint not null, state_actions_id bigint not null, primary key (jpa_repository_state_id, state_actions_id))
create table state_machine (machine_id varchar(255) not null, state varchar(255), state_machine_context blob, primary key (machine_id))
create table transition (id bigint not null, event varchar(255), kind integer, machine_id varchar(255), guard_id bigint, source_id bigint, target_id bigint, primary key (id))
create table transition_actions (jpa_repository_transition_id bigint not null, actions_id bigint not null, primary key (jpa_repository_transition_id, actions_id))
alter table deferred_events add constraint fk_state_deferred_events foreign key (jpa_repository_state_id) references state
alter table state add constraint fk_state_initial_action foreign key (initial_action_id) references action
alter table state add constraint fk_state_parent_state foreign key (parent_state_id) references state
alter table state_entry_actions add constraint fk_state_entry_actions_a foreign key (entry_actions_id) references action
alter table state_entry_actions add constraint fk_state_entry_actions_s foreign key (jpa_repository_state_id) references state
alter table state_exit_actions add constraint fk_state_exit_actions_a foreign key (exit_actions_id) references action
alter table state_exit_actions add constraint fk_state_exit_actions_s foreign key (jpa_repository_state_id) references state
alter table state_state_actions add constraint fk_state_state_actions_a foreign key (state_actions_id) references action
alter table state_state_actions add constraint fk_state_state_actions_s foreign key (jpa_repository_state_id) references state
alter table transition add constraint fk_transition_guard foreign key (guard_id) references guard
alter table transition add constraint fk_transition_source foreign key (source_id) references state
alter table transition add constraint fk_transition_target foreign key (target_id) references state
alter table transition_actions add constraint fk_transition_actions_a foreign key (actions_id) references action
alter table transition_actions add constraint fk_transition_actions_t foreign key (jpa_repository_transition_id) references transition
```

Comment: May I ask how you acquired the SQL statements @helvete?

Comment: There is an option to dump "raw" SQL in Liquibase: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/generate-sql-update-schemas.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create STATE_MACHINE table. After creation the persist feature works like charm.

Following is the mysql script for the said table.

```
CREATE TABLE `STATE_MACHINE`(
    MACHINE_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    STATE VARCHAR(255),
    STATE_MACHINE_CONTEXT BLOB
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You don't need to create the table by hand. The tables are automatically created if the state-machine autoconfiguration is enabled. Also It won't work like a charm, because all the other tables needed for persisting actions, guards, transitions etc. won't be existing (see the complete list of tables below). You will also have to either create them by hand or better rely on the autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled the Spring state machine JPA auto-configuration ([`StateMachineJpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/boot/autoconfigure/StateMachineJpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.java)) this will enable all the default repositories and entities used for persisting states, transitions etc. in a database.
A complete list of those entities and repositories can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-data/jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/data/jpa).

For example the [`JpaRepositoryAction`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-data/jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/data/jpa/JpaRepositoryAction.java) entity will create a table `ACTION`, as can be seein in the entity definition (`@Table(name = "Action"`).

The default db schema looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, default JPA entities are available in State Machine libraries. Just create the tables, records can be inserted automatically as expected.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @mad_fox see the provided answer below