# Spring stateMachine persistance with Jpa

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I got a problem with persister configuration. The problem is similar to [Spring State machine - Table Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855945/spring-state-machine-table-scripts) , but I dont want to generate tables by myself or with liquibase. So I'd like to use **StateMachineJpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration** but I can't find info how I should enable it.
I already tried to use *@ImportAutoConfiguration* and do some stuff in property file, for example:

```
spring:
  statemachine:
    data:
      jpa:
        repositories:
          enabled: true
```

But, unfortunately It didn't work for me, and I still get the error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: missing table [action]

Maybe the way with **StateMachineJpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration** is not suitable here, so I'm needed any advice

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use embedded H2 and all the tables was created. So the problem was in my spring.jpa.hibernate settings.
So it should be spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create